# Bootstrap .btn Looks Different On Safari

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this HTML code :

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  <a href="poweron.php" type="button" class="btn btn-danger text-white">Power On</a>
</div>
```

and here's how it looks like on Safari and Chrome:

[image]

why the power button looks 'grey' and it has different size on Safari but works as I expected on Chrome? How to make it looks exactly same like on the Google Chrome?

Answer (score 7):

You can try adding this style to your `<a>` tag with this code:

```css
a[type='button'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```